# Saving into table on button click

Tags: android

I have an onclick event such as:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View createView) {
    switch (createView.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_button:              
        break;
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked I want to be able to call:

```
public void addAppointment(String string) {
  // Insert a new record into the Events data source.
  // You would do something similar for delete and update.
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(TITLE, string);
  values.put(TIME, string);
  getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

from another class, do I have to import certain parts or make it static?

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to import certain parts or make it static?

No. I suggest you create new instance of your second class(in onCreate() method) and call its method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View createView) {
    switch (createView.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_button: 
        sc.addAppointment("someValue");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, So what would go in <stringValue>? TIME for example? because that part gives an error

Comment: @user2154328 sure,..its pseudocode i don't know what value you want to pass as parameter of addAppointment. its your application man.

Comment: because when put that it gives 'cannot be resolves to variable' error

Comment: I have passed the string value, but when I click on button it crashes

Comment: @user2154328 what logcat says?